# Change the width of table with border-collapse: collapse

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I am fully confused in this situation. When I change the *border-width* of table (dynamically, with JavaScript or in Chrome Dev Tools) with `border-collapse: collapse;` from 1px (**#1**) to *big* value (**#2**) and back to 1px (**#3**), I am get visual defect. **#1** and **#3** are identical, but they have a different appearance. Why is this happening?

**HTML:**

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 1px #ddd solid;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">Crazy Button</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtemFitiskin/6sqcb1ns/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hack-solution is force to redraw item:

```
item.style.display = 'none';
item.offsetHeight; 
item.style.display = 'table';
```